# Como hacer macro para buscar información en otro libro y traerla

Tags: excel

Este es mi ejemplo pero me da error

```
Sub importar()
Dim libroDestino As Workbook
Dim libroOrigen As Workbook
Dim Ruta As String
 
Set libroDestino = ThisWorkbook
Ruta = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Seleccione Libro para traer información")
    
If Ruta = "False" Then
Exit Sub
End If
    
Set libroOrigen = Workbooks.Open(Ruta)
    
For J = 2 To 63

Sheets("Hoja5").Cells(J, 2) = Application.VLookup(Sheets("Hoja5").Cells(J, 1), Application.Workbooks(Ruta).Worksheets("SUELDOS").Range("a2:i70"), 9, False)

Next J
    libroOrigen.Close
 End Sub
```

El error que me da:

[image: Este es el error]

Se agradece cualquier ayuda

Comment: ¿Revisaste [esta pregunta](/q/183891)? ¿Y la [documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/subscript-out-of-range-error-9)? Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio

Answer (score 1):

Hola a todos ya resolví mi problema ahora estoy averiguando como tratar la información cuando no encuentra coincidencias, ya que es muy importante saber cual no encontró.

dejo código

```
 Sub importar()
 
 Dim hojaorigen, hojadestino As Worksheet
 Dim libroDestino As Workbook
 Dim libroOrigen As Workbook
 Dim Ruta As String
 Dim ufilao As Long
 Dim ufilad As Long
 Dim Resultado As String
 
    Set libroDestino = ThisWorkbook
    Set hojadestino = libroDestino.Sheets("hojatmp")
    ufilad = hojadestino.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    
    If Ruta = "False" Then
    Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Ruta = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Seleccione Libro para traer información")
    Set libroOrigen = Workbooks.Open(Ruta)
    Set hojaorigen = libroOrigen.Sheets("SUELDOS")
    ufilao = hojaorigen.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
    For J = 2 To ufilad

On Error Resume Next ' Evita que se produzca un error si no se encuentra el valor
Resultado = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(hojadestino.Cells(J, 1).Value, hojaorigen.Range("A2:I" & ufilao), 9, False)
hojadestino.Cells(J, 2) = Resultado

On Error GoTo 0 ' Restablece el manejo de errores

    Next J
    
    libroOrigen.Close False
        
 End Sub
```

Comment: Hhola Luis, me alegra que lo hayas resuelto y publicado, pasadas las 48hs, puedes marcar tu respuesta como aceptada!!.